# Under the iOS 13 system, I try to present a UIViewController with a semi-transparent background. The background color changed to completely black

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios13

I tried to present the viewController with **semi-transparent** background. However, under **iOS 13**, the background color become completely **Black**(Shown in the Image above)!

I have set modalPresentationStyle and modalTransitionStyle:

```
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```

[image: Black background color]

Help, please!

Comment: try `.overCurrentContext` and set the background color alpha to `0.7`, with the white popup being a subview over the background view.

Comment: Are you presenting it from a viewcontroller? Are you presenting the viewcontroller directly or do you have a navigationcontroller in which viewcontroller is present?

Comment: @Harry J I tried, but still black